# RabbitMQ send messages to users on website

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, python-2.7, rabbitmq

I am trying to use RabbitMQ to send messages to users on a website. While I know how to communicate between different scripts I can't find anything about how I can get a new user to recieve messages.

Let's take chapter 1 of the tutorial as example: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html

How would I be able to send "Hello World" to a user on my website and be displayed in the console? Would it even be possible using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the RabbitMQ Web-STOMP plugin: https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use RabbitMQ for that. It's for communication between different services in your back end, not for sending messages between arbitrary users on your front end.

Comment: There's the RabbitMQ Web STOMP plugin specifically for that: https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html